# How does Google manage to draw under other app's edittexts?

Tags: android

Google usually shows a dropdown in the `EditText` fields, something like this.

A prompt to fill OTP from the microsoft SMS manager app

[image: A prompt to fill OTP from the microsoft SMS manager app]

A dropdown by Google, to fill known data

[image: A dropdown by Google, to fill known data]

How to achieve this behaviour if we are developing an app which will do something similar? i.e, Draw under `EditText`s of other apps.

Comment: Check out the autofill api: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be acheive by using Android Framork called as [Autofill framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill)

Find the samples here by Google team 
https://github.com/android/input-samples

The autofill framework contains the following high-level components:

**Autofill services:** Apps such as password managers that save and store the user information that can be used in views across multiple apps.

**Autofill clients:** Apps that provide the views that need to be filled out or that hold the user's data.

**Android system:** The OS that defines the workflow and provides the infrastructure that makes services and clients work together.

For a detailed explanation of the autofill workflow, see the [AutofillManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager) and [AutofillService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService) reference documentation.

Well written blog post about it - 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811